# Mixing Fondant Icing to make Pink

Tags: cake, fondant

I have some White and Red Fondant icing left over from a cake I made recently, I have another cake to make for my mother in-law, and need Pink icing.

If I mix the white and red together, will I get some pink icing which I can work with?

The Red can be seen here, it is what the red balls are made of.

[image]

Comment: Cool snooker cake! Is the chalk fondant?

Comment: No I didn't attempt the chalk! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can mix red and white fondant to make pink fondant, red is just white that's dyed so mixing red into white will dilute the red dye. It takes a lot of dye to get a strong red color but very little to get pink, so start with 10% red to 90% white first and see how you get.

Comment: Will it be ok though? I have found in the past that too much combining fondants can leave it a bit "loose" and cracks a lot.

Comment: When you work fondant it can get dry @TimBJames. If it gets too dry it cracks and loses consistency. A spray bottle of water on mist would help with that.